Enabling incsearch only in focused window
I have been trying to enable incsearch only for the window which is currently in focus, along with adjusting the highlight settings according to my preference. So, the options sit in options.lua file in lua folder called by init.lua using require('options'), there is no problem in the calling as all the configurations previously defined seems to work well.
To achieve incsearch only in the window focus I defined the following augroup (first one is copied from docs (here) and the second I managed myself),
augroup vimrc-incsearch-highlight
  autocmd!
  autocmd CmdlineEnter /,\? :set hlsearch
  autocmd CmdlineLeave /,\? :set nohlsearch
augroup END

vim.cmd([[
  augroup FocusedSearchHighlight
    autocmd!
    autocmd WinEnter * setlocal hlsearch
    autocmd WinLeave * setlocal nohlsearch
  augroup END
]])

But it didn't seem too work so I translated it to vim.api.nvim_create_augroup by seeing this question and seeing through Neovim docs for few options and methods.
Then I integrated it with highlight settings I want under conman group highlights, thus creating the following code:
local highlights = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("Highlight", { clear = true })
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd(
  {"CmdlineEnter"},
  {pattern = {"/", ",", "?"},
  callback = function()
      vim.opt.hlsearch = true
    end,
  group = highlights
  }
)

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd(
  {"CmdlineLeave"},
  {pattern = {"/", ",", "?"},
  callback = function()
      vim.opt.hlsearch = false
    end,
  group = highlights
  }
)

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("WinEnter", {
  group = highlights,
  callback = function()
    if vim.v.hlsearch then
      vim.opt_local.hlsearch = true
    end
  end,
})

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("WinLeave", {
  group = highlights,
  callback = function()
    vim.opt_local.hlsearch = false
  end,
})

I want to achieve following behavior: Whenever a pattern is searched through / cursorline command search only in the activated window and leave the highlight when esc or enter is clicked.
Questions

Why is / still searching across all the windows in the tab?
Is the highlight behavior settings I made even necessary, as after saving them I check by commenting them but the / was still removing highlights after Esc or Enter is clicked, is it the default behavior?

I don't know if code is exactly what I expect it to behave like but I have a decent outline of what the code must be doing. I must say that I have only very basic knowledge of lua, any help would be appreciated.

Here is my attempt to answer your questions:
1. Why is / still searching accross all the windows in the tab
The 'incsearch' option is a global option. You can't set it for a specific window. (More information with :help 'incsearch'
Not exactly what you are searching but you could be interested by the following vim-localsearch plugin.
2. Is the highlight behavior settings I made even necessary, as after saving them I check by commenting them but the / was still removing highlights after Esc or Enter is clicked, is it the default behavior?
Yes it is. If 'incsearch' option is set. The result of the match are highlighted unless the :nohlsearch command is issued. You can test that with starting Neovim with the --clear flag:
nvim --clear

The vim-noh plugin automatically triggers :noh when the cursors moves. There are a number of contenders:

vim-slash
vim-oblique


thanks, that answers most off, in that case the whole code block was unnecessary, quick followup question,1) Can there be any workaround to set incsearch for window only? 2) why doesn't it work when called with :/ rather than directly using /, is there any underline technical aspect to it?

Unfortunately I see no workarround. But of course that doesn't guarantee that there is not, hope is still allowed :-)
